# Determine if directory is writeable

Tags: c++, unit-testing, exception, boost, ofstream

I need to determine, from within a C++ program, whether a directory on a Linux filesystem is writeable or not. My original (naive) solution was to open a file and attempt to write to it using an `ofstream`, but streams don't throw exceptions (unless you turn them on).

Here is my attempt #1. Note that `/tmp/protectedstorage-test/mnt` is mounted as read-only before running the test case):

```
class create_test_file_failed {};

void create_test_file() {
    std::ofstream os;
    os.open("/tmp/protectedstorage-test/mnt/test_file", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
    if (os.fail())
        throw create_test_file_failed{};
    os << MAGIC_NUMBER;
    os.close();
}

bool not_writable_exception_check(std::exception const& ex) {
    return true;
}

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE ( uninitialized_mirror_test ) {
    BOOST_CHECK_EXCEPTION(create_test_file, create_test_file_failed, not_writable_exception_check);
}
```

However, `os.fail()` seems to always return false. I also tried `os.bad()` with no success.

So, here is my second attempt:

```
void create_test_file() {
    std::ofstream os;
    os.exceptions(std::ofstream::failbit | std::ofstream::badbit);
    os.open("/tmp/protectedstorage-test/mnt/test_file", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
    os << MAGIC_NUMBER;
    os.close();
}

bool not_writable_exception_check(std::exception const& ex) {
    return true;
}

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE ( uninitialized_mirror_test ) {
    BOOST_CHECK_EXCEPTION(create_test_file, std::exception, not_writable_exception_check);
}
```

This results in the following message when I run the unit test:

```
halfmirror_test.cpp(66): error in "uninitialized_mirror_test": exception std::exception is expected
```

If I remove the macro `BOOST_CHECK_EXCEPTION` and simply call the function, I get the following message implying that an exception derived from `std::exception` was thrown:

```
unknown location(0): fatal error in "uninitialized_mirror_test": std::exception: basic_ios::clear
```

Since `basic_ios::clear` is a method, not a type, it seems like I should be catching `std::exception`...

What's going on here? Why isn't `fail()` working? What type is being thrown so I can verify it's actually being thrown?

I've seen other answers suggesting that inspecting file permissions is the best way to accomplish this, but those permissions don't really tell you anything on a read-only filesystem - a file with writeable permissions really isn't in that case.

Comment: What happens if you check `fail()` after you've attempted to write, not just after `open()`?

Comment: Take a look at the example code at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html.

Comment: I am pretty sure that if you mount a filesystem read-only all the files will appear to be read-only, regardless of the permissions when the file system in mounted normally.

Comment: `stat` does not appear to change the data it returns based upon whether the filesystem is mounted read-only or not. Unless I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: I ended up using `touch` to attempt to create a file and then examining the exit code. I'm leaving this question open, though, in the hopes that someone can answer why `fail()` doesn't work, or what exception `open()` is throwing in this situation.

Answer (score -3):

[stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) is your friend.

```
stat, fstat, lstat - get file status
```

If you are using boost, consider [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)

Comment: I'm working on verifying `stat` will do what I want. I am using `boost::filesystem` already for other things. Does it have the capability of determining that a file is not writeable (even though it has +w on it)?

Comment: @Steve I am fairly certain the the effective permissions are what stat/boost::filesystem will report, not the permissions of the files when the disk is mounted "normally".   boost::filesystem has a "status" function that behaves much like stat.

Comment: I just looked at the struct returned by stat, and when I compare the values of each field I get the same results whether the filesystem is mounted read-only or not. I would expect at least `st_mode` to change, but I get the value `33204` (decimal) in both cases.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong then.  A careful reading of some man pages, makes it look like stat returns info about the inode, not the "file".  If this is correct, then it would agree with what you are seeing.  Annoying, but useful to know.

Comment: Link only answer - doesn't actually say *how* to check if a directory is writable.